# ng-switch sliding transition inside div container

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrapper 3 panel and ng-switch with a sliding animation: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXJpZHRSmMKbtAZ20VEe?p=preview)

I want to only show the animation inside the panel, when the animation plays the div is showing past the panel borders.

What am I missing in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXJpZHRSmMKbtAZ20VEe?p=preview) so that the animation only shows inside the panel div?

The result that I am looking for is somewhat like this sample: [slider-css3-transition-animation](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation)

But I cant seem to get a grasp of how to structure my css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by adding in your css :

```
.panel {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Here is the result in your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WUCyCN68tDR1YzNnCWyS?p=preview)

Comment: the resizing of the panel when switching looks a little buggy.. maybe enough to ask another question :)

Comment: Created a new question regarding the resizing of the panel when switching: [ng-switch with animation resizing looks buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115016/ng-switch-with-animation-resizing-looks-buggy)

Comment: How can I change the code so that when the page jsut loaded the first panel is already loaded and not sliding?