# ng-switch with animation resizing looks buggy

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transitions

Using ng-switch with animation inside a div container I am struggling to figure out how to avoid the div from resizing when the animation is running [see this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vhaFgocgZ36uhRTxqrx2?p=preview)

If I set the height of the div it obviously shows correctly but the 3 containers used in the switch is different sizes and one of the containers can maybe have a dynamic size like some long text.

Is there maybe a fix for this with some CSS magic or is it down to some JavaScript to calculate the div height?

I did come across this similar question but it doesn’t solve my problem: [Angularjs ng-animate + css transition for sliding effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860783/angularjs-ng-animate-css-transition-for-sliding-effect)